# Unable to connect WKExtensionDelegate in Xcode 14 watch app

Tags: xcode, watchos

In the Apple developer docs chapter "[There and Back Again](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10003/?time=63)" the watch app's App is written like this:

```
@main
struct MyWatchApp: App {
    
    @WKExtensionDelegateAdaptor(ExtensionDelegate.self) var extensionDelegate
    
    @SceneBuilder var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get a purple runtime warning on my var declaration that says

> @WKExtensionDelegateAdaptor should only be used within an extension based process

There must be something in Xcode that explicitly defines the App structure as "extension-based" but I can't find it!

Edit: More clarification... I am trying to handle the special method that gets called after you run the HealthKit method [startWatchApp(with:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1648358-startwatchapp)

The special method for watch extensions is [func handle(_ workoutConfiguration: HKWorkoutConfiguration)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextensiondelegate/1650871-handle)
I cannot seem to find a way to link this function on the new `App` structure for watch apps.

Comment: I wish I could download a copy of their sample project but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, I found it. The solution is to simply replace `WKExtensionDelegate` with the new `WKApplicationDelegate`!

Comment: You also need to change the name of the "adaptor":
    @WKApplicationDelegateAdaptor private var extensionDelegate: ExtensionDelegate

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution, it is simple and universal.

```
import WatchKit

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {
    
    static var current: ExtensionDelegate? {
       return (WKExtension.shared().delegate as? ExtensionDelegate)
    }
...
}
```

Then access this current instance like below, because it is Singleton, you can access it in the entire project scope.

```
ExtensionDelegate.current?.dosomething()
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstand. I'm not trying to access an instance. I'm just trying to conform to the WKExtensionDelegate protocol on Xcode 14. I've added some clarification. Thank you!